# AJAX behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to pass a variable back to xmlhttp.responseText. I have two separate functions that do this. The first is called when the page loads and is successful. The second gets called on a click and while it executes correctly on the PHP side (it makes changes in my MYSQL database) if I insert an alert into the AJAX function to check the readyState no alert pops up (but it will with the first). It also never receives the variable returned from PHP in the xmlhttp.responseText.

What could be preventing the readyState from changing the second time, even though the functions on the PHP side are executing?

PHP:

```js
function checkNow()
{
global $usercrypt;
global $place;
$urow = mysql_query("SELECT Users.User FROM Users WHERE Users.User='" . $usercrypt . "';");
 if (mysql_num_rows($urow) > 0)
 {
 $favcheck = mysql_query("SELECT Users.Favorites FROM Users WHERE Users.User='" . $usercrypt . "';");
 $favcheck = mysql_fetch_array($favcheck);
 $favcheck = $favcheck[0];
  if (strpos($favcheck, $place) !== false)
  {
  $answer = 'found';
  }
  else
  {
  $answer = 'notfound';
  }
 }
 else
 {
 $answer = 'nouser';
 }
return array($answer,$favcheck);
unset($answer);
}
 
if ($perform == "0")
{
$sendback = checkNow();
echo $sendback[0];
unset($sendback);
}

if ($perform == "1")
{
global $usercrypt;
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Users (User) VALUES ('" . $usercrypt . "')");
}

if ($perform == "2")
{
$sendback = checkNow();
global $place;
global $placeid;
global $usercrypt;
$currentnum = mysql_query("SELECT Places.Favorites FROM Places WHERE Places.PlaceID=" . $placeid);
$currentnum = mysql_fetch_array($currentnum);
$currentnum = $currentnum[0];
 if ($sendback[0] == 'found')
 {
 $currentnum--;
 $change = str_replace($place,'',$sendback[1]);
 mysql_query("UPDATE Users SET Favorites='" . $change . "' WHERE User = '" . $usercrypt . "'");
 mysql_query("UPDATE Places SET Places.Favorites=" . $currentnum . " WHERE Places.PlaceID =" . $placeid);
 echo 'subtracted';
 }
 if ($sendback[0] == 'notfound')
 {
 $currentnum++;
 $change = $sendback[1] . $place;
 mysql_query("UPDATE Users SET Favorites='" . $change . "' WHERE User = '" . $usercrypt . "'");
 mysql_query("UPDATE Places SET Places.Favorites=" . $currentnum . " WHERE Places.PlaceID =" . $placeid);
 echo 'added';
 }
}
```

JavaScript:

```html
function ajaxSession()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
 z = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
}

function stateCheck()
{
ajaxSession();
xmlhttp.open('POST', thisurl + '/favoritecheck.php',true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xmlhttp.send("0=" + perform + "&1=" + thisplace + ",&2=" + thisusername);
}


function firstCheck()
{
perform = 0;
stateCheck();
 if (z == 'found')
 {
 document.getElementById("favorite").src="http://www.********.com/images/favorite-on.png";
 document.getElementById("favtext").innerHTML="This is a favorite!";
 }
 if ( z == 'nouser')
 {
 perform = 1;
 stateCheck();
 }
}

function heartCheck()
{
perform = 2;
stateCheck();
 if (z == 'added')
 {
 document.getElementById("favorite").src="http://www.********.com/images/favorite-on.png";
 document.getElementById("favtext").innerHTML="This is a favorite!";
 }
 if (z == 'subtracted')
 {
 document.getElementById("favorite").src="http://www.********.com/images/favorite-off.png";
 document.getElementById("favtext").innerHTML="Add to your favorites.";
 }
}
```

Clicky-clicky:

```js
if (loggedin == 1)
{
document.writeln('<img id="favorite" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="heartCheck()" src="http://www.********.com/images/favorite-off.png" alt="Favorite" />'
+ '<br />'
+ '<div id="favtext" style="color: #D20425;">'
+ 'Add to your favorites.'
+ '</div>');
firstCheck();
} else if (loggedin == 0)
{
document.writeln('<img id="favorite" style="cursor: pointer;" src="http://www.********.com/images/favorite-off.png" alt="Favorite" />'
+ '<br />'
+ '<div id="favtext" style="color: #D20425;">'
+ '<a style="color: #800000; font-weight: bold;" href="' + thisurl + '/wp-login.php">Log in</a> to add favorites.'
+ '</div>');
}
```

heartCheck() is run on the click. firstCheck() runs when the page is loaded.

Comment: Provide your code...

Comment: Sounds like you are not cancelling the click action, but without actual code, that is just an educated guess.

Comment: Click on what? Also, you have switched the titles javascript and php but I don't think anybody will mistake one for the other :-)

Comment: When is `thisurl` defined?

Comment: *fixed the PHP/JavaScript labels.

thisurl is defined earlier in the page in an external script.